# Copying wallpaper images into a single folder

Tags: shell-script, find, rename, cp

In my ubuntu 12.04 set-up, there are lots of wallpaper images in the directory `/usr/share/wallpapers`.  For example, one might be

```
usr/share/wallpapers/Leafs_Labyrinth/contents/images/1600x1200.jpg
```

What I want to do is travel through the wallpapers directory, pick out all the images of size `1600x...` or `1680x...` and copy them to another folder, but renamed, so that the above image would end up being called `Leafs_Labyrinth1600x1200.jpg`.

I can't use `find` alone here; I expect I need to use some sort of shell script, of which I have very little experience.  Is there an easy "natural" way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

This should work based on the details of your question. You can save the following in a file, change **mydirectory** to the name of your target folder, and then run `bash name_of_script`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# * matches any string | [08] matches 0 and 8
for image in /usr/share/wallpapers/*/contents/images/16[08]0x*.jpg; do
    # create variables by cutting $image in pieces separated by /
    name=$(awk -F/ '{print $5}' <<<$image)
    file=$(awk -F/ '{print $8}' <<<$image)

    # copy to "mydirectory"
    cp "$image" mydirectory/"$name""$file"
done
```

The same can be simplified like this:

```
for image in /usr/share/wallpapers/*/contents/images/16[08]0x*.jpg; do
    cp "$image" mydirectory/"$(awk -F/ '{print $5 $8}' <<<$image)"
done
```